# Calling Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Identify gets stuck in an infinite loop for one costumer

Tags: mongodb, contact

We are on Sitecore 8.2.

When calling `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Identify()`, the `mongo db` call gets stuck in an infinite loop for only one costumer.  It looks like the xdbContactIdentifier is not in the mongo table and it keeps trying to find it.